# Jquery accordion tweak for inactive state

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Hi I have this simple accordion set to change background color when selected and return to white when deselected... it works great apart from when I click on the active  to close the accordion and the background doesnt change back... Any help would be appreciated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(".accordion > dt").click(function(){
    if(false == $j(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $j('.accordion dd').slideUp(300);
        $j('.accordion dt').css('backgroundColor','#ffffff');
    }
    $j(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    $j(this).css('backgroundColor','#EE178C');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm perplexed why you're doing this all with multiple jQuery operations when Accordion's [beforeActivate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate) can handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

this jquery plugin i threw together should do it:

```
    (function ( $ ) {
     var backgroundColorToggleStatus = null;
    $.fn.backgroundColorToggle = function(one,two) {
        return this.each(function(){
                if (backgroundColorToggleStatus == one)
                    backgroundColorToggleStatus = two;
                else if (backgroundColorToggleStatus == two)
                    backgroundColorToggleStatus = one;
            else{
                    backgroundColorToggleStatus = one;
            }
            $(this).css("backgroundColor",backgroundColorToggleStatus);
        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

simply call `.backgroundColorToggle("#fff","#000");` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gph6J/2/).

Comment: Thanks for trying but the problem persists ie if you click to activate the accordion its fine but if you click again to close it stays pink - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gph6J/

Comment: @user2595800 that should do it. simple little jquery plugin. [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/gph6J/2/).